# minify teamcity log written by tests launched by gradle

Tags: gradle, logging, teamcity

I have a *gradle* build step in a *teamcity* configuration which does `build test`.
There are a lot of text being logged by the tests. More than a gigabyte.
Is it possible to filter test output out of the general log but still have it on the **Tests** *teamcity*'s tab when I click on the test?

Comment: What language are the tests written in? What test framework are you using?

Answer (score 0):

The fact that tests are outputting 1GB+ of text is concerning. Ideally, the test runner should be the only thing outputting text (ie: pass, fail indications and error messages)—the tests themselves should not be outputting any text. Consider supressing/capturing stdout from tests, broadly.

Since the language you are testing/test framework is not specified in the question, I am unable to specifically determine what changes you need to make, but there is typically an idiosyncratic way to do this depending on language/test framework.

Comment: the project is in java/kotlin. most of the tests are made with junit